ubuntu 22.04 screen freeze
I have an error that started 2-3 weeks ago and has been getting worse lately. Although I can easily use it in any application without freezing, Ubuntu freezes every time I open a new application or folder. To make matters worse, sometimes one of my screens freezes and doesn't get fixed without resetting the interface. I tried to show it by making a video to make it more descriptive. I'm waiting for your help
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7LDr7BDToiA

What did you do 2 to 3 weeks ago? Installed updates? Installed new apps? Did a shut down with the power switch? Your question needs some details added. Please use edit to add the details not in a comment.

I downloaded a few games from Steam. While installing the games I updated all my hardware, deleted and reinstalled my GPU driver (but as far as I remember it was doing this before updating my graphics card driver). I was using dualboot and I completely deleted the part of my disk reserved for Windows with gparted. These are transactions I have made recently. The screenshot shows all the programs I have installed in the last 3 weeks. https://prnt.sc/2bkaSH4l--IF

"Did a shut down with the power switch?" If you mean force shutting down with your question, yes, I think I did it many times.

Then there is a very good chance you have corrupted the OS.   BTW I asked you not to use the comments and to edit the question. Why have you had to use the power switch to shut down?

Sorry, this is my first time using the forum. Sometimes both my monitors freeze and I can't open the command line, so I have to force a restart with the power button.

Every time you do this you may corrupt the OS even more. It may not be a popular answer but I suggest a fresh install.

Of course a clean install is the best solution but I was hoping there was another solution :( . I'll be switching to a new computer next week. I think I can manage like this for another week. Thanks for help.
